# Induced action of topological groups

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a polish group, $H$ be an open subgroup of $G$ and $X$ be any metric space on which $G$ act. I want to show the following fact:

If the restriction to $H $of the action of $G$ on $X$ is continuous, then the action of $G$ on $X$ is continuous.

Thank for any help

Comment: This can be shown using the same trick as the one I used in the answer to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267024/polish-groups-and-open-subgroups), i.e., testing sequential continuity, exploiting that $G/H$ is discrete.